# Is it possible to write one sql query for this job: select, then compare then insert/update

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to deal with a table in MariaDB for students' grade. When a student send a new grade, I need to first check if a student's record exists in the table, if yes, update if the new grade is higher than the existing one. If the student does not exist in the table, insert as a new record.

Following is my PHP code (for simplicity, suppose the students name is John and his new grade is 100, `$conn` is the `mysqli` object):

```
$result =  $conn->query("select name, grade from grade_sheet where name='john' and grade<100");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $conn->query("update grade_sheet set grade=100 where name='john'");
} else {
    $conn->query("insert into grade_sheet (name, grade) values ('john', 100)");
}
```

Is it possible to simplify the code? More specifically, is it possible to use like `insert ... on duplicate key update`?

Here `name` is the primary key. Is it true that, in the worst case, the above code needs to search the table twice?

Comment: Your code is already simple enough. Trying to make it in a single sql statement will make it harder to read and understand. It is already just fine. Is there a more specific reason you want it in one code?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I mean if `insert ... on duplicate key update` can be used here? In worst case, the above code needs to search the table twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what's mentioned in the comments, this is the wrong approach and you are right to want to change this. The reason that you should change it is to avoid race conditions, the possibility that another thread will modify the records of interest in between your two queries.

Performance vice there will not be much of a difference if you have an proper index, but if you are doing this sort of query you probably don't. You should be having an auto increment primary key on this table and refer to it using that column rather than 'John' which is very unlikely to be unique. There should then be a foreign key to a students table which records student names

Then you can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to get the job done in a single query. Safely.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the documents so is the following query correct: `insert into grade_sheet (name, grade) values ('john', 100) on duplicate key update grade = if(grade < 100, 100, grade)`

Comment: And now I used the student id number to be the primary key, which is unique.

Comment: i would use a numeric key here instead of 'john' since john isn't likely to be unique